# Need properties to pass to google chart javascript

Tags: php, jquery

I am working with WordPress so I checked if it was a typical WordPress question, but it is a usual php and jQuery question.

I have a piece of code which is executed 12 times with different data. I have to collect this data with jQuery and pass it to another widget which will be shown only if I click a widget is clicked. The other widget must show the data of the clicked widget and present a google chart. The show on purpose and google chart thing is no problem, my only problem is to pass the data. I tried a lot of things but I am new to jQuery and have definitely a lack of skills at the moment so I hope you guys can help me. I have simplified the code to show you the examples and structure.

The code which will be executed 12 times:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="span1 <?php echo $color .' '. $styleName; ?>">
    <div class="box_top">
        <div class="icon"></div>
        <div class="title"><h2><?php echo $title; ?></h2></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box_middle">
        <?php echo $currentValue; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="box_bottom">
        <div class="lastweek">
            <p>Last week:</p>
        </div>
        <div class="number">
            <?php echo $prevValue; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

The only difference between this widget and the other widget will be that in the class span1 will be span5.

To make a long story short: I need to collect the data of the variables so I can pass them to another widget, can somebody help me with this or push me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select values straight from html but better to use [jQuery data](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/).

### HTML

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-current="<?php echo $currentValue; ?>" data-prev="<?php echo $prevValue; ?>" data-title="<?php echo $title; ?>" class="span1 <?php echo $color .' '. $styleName; ?>">
    <div class="box_top">
        <div class="icon"></div>
        <div class="title"><h2><?php echo $title; ?></h2></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box_middle">
        <?php echo $currentValue; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="box_bottom">
        <div class="lastweek">
            <p>Last week:</p>
        </div>
        <div class="number">
            <?php echo $prevValue; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

### jQuery

```
$('body').on('click','.span1',function(){
    var title=$(this).data('title');
    var cur=$(this).data('current');
    var prev=$(this).data('prev');

    alert(title+': '+prev+' - '+cur);
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response!
It did the job for me, I added an id to so I can mark them per widget.
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome. Yes always better to work with ids instead of classes.